# Passar lista de objetos entre arquivos

Tags: javascript, array, orientação-a-objetos, objetos

Como passar uma lista de objetos através de dois arquivos JavaScript?

Tenho uma lista:

```
var elementsList = [];
```

E esta lista é populada com N objetos:

```
var oElement = {
    elem: "",
    emin: 0.0000,
    emax: 0.0000
}
```

Eu preciso passar isto tudo para uma janela modal:

```
var oElem = {
            "id": "FCADELEM",
            "data-height": "558",
            "data-width": "320",
            "data-name": "Elementos Químicos",
            "data-url": "FCADELEM.aspx?returnToForm=ifr_FCADQUAL",
            "data-module": "Elementos Químicos",
            "attr": function (param) {
                return this[param];
            }
        }
        parent.createDialog(oElem);
```

Como posso passar esta lista de objetos para a outra janela sem usar o C#?

INFORMAÇÕES COMPLEMENTARES

- As duas janelas em questão são iframes Modal, da biblioteca jQuery.
- Não é possível armazenar os dados no js da página 'mãe'.
- As duas janelas são do mesmo domínio.

Comment: Não percebo o seu problema. Pode explicar melhor? A array e o objeto estão em ficheiros/páginas diferentes? em diferentes momentos?

Comment: E basicamente, eu abro uma janela modal ao clicar em um botão, parent.createDialog(oElem); cria o modal, e eu preciso desta lista dentro do JS do modal, que devo abrir.

Comment: O seu modal é uma iFrame? se não, então está tudo disponível. Pode ter de ajustar o escopo, mas parece-me simples de resolver. Mais uma duvida. Qual é a relação entre os dois? Por exemplo o 1o el da array tem a ver com que parte do objeto?

Comment: A janela de onde vem os dados também é um iframe, não é possível armazenar na pagina pai. Então, teoricamente, é como se fosse de uma página para outra.

Comment: Ok, e a iFrame está no mesmo domínio? e já agora, usa alguma biblioteca como jQuery ou MooTools?

Comment: William, com os detalhes que faltavam à pergunta vai ser possível responder com a solução. Pode acrescentar esta informação na pergunta também para ficar mais completa.

Comment: Sim, no mesmo domínio, uso jQuery.

Comment: William, coloquei uma resposta. Não sei qual é o modal que usa, se não fôr o do jQuery UI diga qual é que eu posso ajustar a resposta.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Obrigado pela colaboração Sérgio, ajudou bastante para o desenrolar da questão, mas tive que fazer algumas adaptações, pois a lista de objetos é um pouco mais complexa do que uma string, por exemplo..

A resolução, se deu da seguinte forma:

Pensei em usar PostMessage, mas para isso precisaria que o iframe modal estivesse aberto, primeiro passo então, criar o modal.
No modal recém criado, volta ao iframe anterior, e recolhe o objeto. Chamamos a função **getItem()** no onload.

```
function getItem() {
    try {
        var returnToUrl = "FCADQUAL.aspx";
        var msgAddr = window.location.protocol + "//" + window.location.host + returnToUrl;
        var o = parent.document.getElementById("ifr_FCADQUAL");
        o.contentWindow.postMessage("100;0", msgAddr);
    } catch (e) {
        Save Exception();
    }
}
```

No iframe anterior então, recebe a mesagem post, e adiciona o objeto ao parametro, e o manda de volta:

```
window.addEventListener("message", receiveMessage, false);

function receiveMessage(e) {
    try {
        //url que verifica se post message é valido
        var url = window.location.protocol + "//" + window.location.host
        //testa se origem do post é do mesmo dominio
        if (e.origin !== url)
            return;
            var sData = e.data.split(";")

            //Solicita informações do item para a tela de informações diversas
            sendInfoDiver();

    } catch (e) {
        Save Exception();
    }
}

function sendInfoDiver() {
    try {
        var returnToUrl = "FCADELEM.aspx";
        var msgAddr = window.location.protocol + "//" + window.location.host + returnToUrl;
        var o = parent.document.getElementById("ifr_FCADELEM");
        o.contentWindow.postMessage(elementsList, msgAddr);
    } catch (e) {
        Save Exception();
    }
}
```

Depois, já na tela modal que recem foi aberta, recebe o objeto e inicia o tratamento.

```
window.addEventListener("message", receiveMessage, false);

function receiveMessage(e) {
    try {
        //url que verifica se post message é valido
        var url = window.location.protocol + "//" + window.location.host
        //testa se origem do post é do mesmo dominio
        if (e.origin !== url)
            return;

        if (typeof e.data == "object") {
            //Recebe o objeto item e popula campos do formulário
            setData(e.data);
        }

        //Oculta a mensagem de loading
        parent.hideLoading();

    } catch (e) {
       Save Exception();
    }
}

function setData(PlReturn) {
...
}
```

E para mandar os dados atualizados de volta, basta fazer o caminho inverso.

Agradeço a colaboração, e fica a fonte de pesquisa para futuras dúvidas da comunidade.

Abraço

Comment: William, bom você ter respondido com detalhe. Dá para editar a pergunta coma informação que lhe faltava? assim fica mais claro para quem procurar solução para o mesmo problema.

Answer (score 2):

Para aceder por exemplo a uma função dentro de uma iFrame no mesmo dominio pode fazer assim:

```
var iFrame = $('#myIframe')[0].contentWindow;
iFrame.receberDadosExternos('Olá!!');
```

Isto implica que haja uma função dentro do iFrame com esse nome e que esteja no escopo global.

Exemplo:

```
function receberDadosExternos(dados) {
    alert(dados);
}
```

[**Exemplo ao vivo**](http://jsfiddle.net/TD7L5/)

No exemplo no jsFiddle que coloquei em cima uso este código que corre só quando o dialog abre:

```
$("#dialog").dialog({
    autoOpen: false,
    modal: true,
    height: 600,
    open: function (ev, ui) {
        var iFrame = $('#myIframe')[0].contentWindow;
        iFrame.receberDadosExternos('Olá!!');
    }
});
```

Mas pode chamar a função quando quiser e passar o que quiser para dentro dela.

No caso de querer o contrário, ie chamar uma função de dentro da iFrame para a janela "mãe" pode usar javascript simples, ou seja:

```
window.parent.nomeDaFuncao();
```